# Find the format that is visualized in a dataframe from a datetime type column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, feature-extraction

I have a problem, that I am not able to automatically solve since I just cannot find how to do it. I would like to extract the format of a datetime column that is visualized when a dataframe is printed.

I have a column within my dataframe that is of the type datetime.datetime. If I print the dataframe I get the following:
[image]

And if I print one value I get this:
[image]

I am not sure what the approach is to easily return the format of the values in the upper image. Just to be clear, I would like to have code that will return the format, that is shown in the dataframe, in datetime codes. In this example it should return: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`.

I am able to return this by first transforming the column to string values and then use the function `_guess_datetime_format_for_array()` from `pandas.core.tools.datetimes`, but this approach is a bit excessive in my opinion. Does anyone have a suggestion of a more easy solution?

Comment: To clarify: `datetime` is a data type to represent date and time, it has no "format" (neither does a float or an int for example). This is why you can only extract a format if you convert datetime to string first. So, are you looking for the default formats pandas is using to display datetime?

Comment: I understand that datetime is a data type, however I want to extract how it is visualized within the dataframe ones you print it. I do believe a float also could have a specific format, maybe it has 4 decimals for all values within the column.

Comment: I do not particularly want the default pandas format, if I understand you correctly. I want the format how it is 'shown'. Another example, some columns might only have date of birth where the format of this would satisfy either '%Y-%m-%d' or '%Y-%d-%m' (not taking into account characters as '/' etc.).

Comment: By "float" I mean the data type; the representation of a floating point number in the computer's memory. By "format" I mean *how* it is represented in a string of characters. So in that sense, float has no format. Only after you convert it to string, e.g. to print it, then it has a format in that string. For example with four decimal places as you suggest ;-)

Comment: So in conclusion, only the 'format' can be determined by first transforming it to string, where you can define the specific structure (format) of the column by decomposing it?

Comment: I think pandas uses a few different [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-based formats, depending on how your datetime column looks like. For example if all Timestamps have micro- and nanoseconds all zero, the format will only have milliseconds / 3 decimal places of fractional seconds (as you show in the screenshot). If hour, minute, second are also zero, only the date is shown. You could implement similar checks to derive the appropriate format.